# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout Android RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm stuck in E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; Skipping layout error please help me to solve the error.  I read most of related answers which are already  present but error is still present.  Help me please give me some possible solutions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this issue is to attach an empty adapter to the `RecyclerView`:

```
void initializeRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(getCurrentActivity()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getCurrentActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
```

Call this method in `onCreateView()` or `onCreate()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the layout manager for the RecyclerView ?

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Make sure you call these methods in the `onCreate()` for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

When the Views are attach they go through layout-phase. Layout event is propagated to the children that are of type `ViewGroup` to start laying out their children too. Which means that at that layout phase your `RecyclerView` attempts to layout views from the adapter. If the adapter returns item count 0 or it isn't set at all, the layout phase does nothing for your `RecyclerView`. Given this, `RecyclerView` will `requestLayout()` when the adapter is set and will start laying out views as soon as adapter has been provided.

That message does not contribute towards your application performance and it isn't critical. You can safely ignore it.